# How can I see what karma sees when I use browser().navigateTo()

Tags: angularjs, testing, karma-runner, end-to-end

I am just getting started with karma, and although it seems that everything is hooked up properly and my unit tests are being run as expected, I can't get my end to end tests to find any elements.

When I go to the debug page, I can see a very brief flash of my application, which says to me that my proxy and config in general is hooked up properly, but when I run

```
describe('my app', function() {
  beforeEach(function(){
     browser().navigateTo('/');
  });
  it('should display the home page', function() {
     expect(element('title').text()).toEqual('my title');
  });
});
```

it never finds an element, no matter the selector I put in.

My question, though, is... is there some way that I can see what it *is* seeing? Can I get karma to dump the full text of the html response? If I could do that, I could at least see what it is getting back. As it stands, I am getting no debugging information at all and it is kind of frustrating.

Feel free to ask for more information if I can make it easier to answer the question. Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pause()` inside your test to pause the execution, then you can resume from the UI.

The docs for `pause()` are [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.e2e-testing).

You can also use `sleep(seconds)` to make a timed pause, if you want to auto resume.